# Get data from Oracle SP through PHP PDO [Output is cursor]

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, pdo

Can someone help me on how to call the stored procedure in oracle by php PDO? I have a following stored procedure.

`sp_getpricedetailforhp (p_pbook in NVARCHAR2,p_plevel in NVARCHAR2,p_item in NVARCHAR2,p_qty in NUMBER,p_date in date,p_customer in NVARCHAR2,c_data OUT sys_refcursor)`

the above stored procedure named sp_getpricedetailforhp used to display a price and It output a cursor. Can someone help me to call the above stored procedure in php PDO. Im new on playing with stored procedure

Following code I tried but no any luck

```
$output ='';
$query = "CALL sp_getpricedetailforhp(:p_pbook, :p_plevel, :p_item, :p_qty, :p_date, :p_customer, @c_data)";
        $stmt= DBInitialize::MiddleSCM2DBPDO()->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':p_pbook' => 'ABANS',
            ':p_plevel' => 'A',
            ':p_item' => 'ABCK1800',
            ':p_qty' => '1',
            ':p_date' => '05/May/2016',
            ':p_customer' => 'N/A',
            ':c_data' => $output,
        ));

print_r($output);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can referance this from

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#101993

```
$dbh->query("CALL SomeStoredProcedure($someInParameter1, $someInParameter2, @someOutParameter)"); 
$dbh->query("SELECT @someOutParameter");

// OR, if you want very much to use PDO.Prepare(),
// insert "SELECT @someOutParameter" in your stored procedure and then use:

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL SomeStoredProcedure(?, ?)"); 
$stmt ->execute(array($someInParameter1, $someInParameter2));
```

Comment: with '@' you can get output 
mini example

while($row = $results2->fetch_object())
    {
    echo $row->{"@p_userid"};
    }

Comment: But my sp getting a cursor. so how I do that?

Comment: please read this 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html

Comment: I've been able to successfully do this by using the OCI functions,
but no such luck with PDO. Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: when I go to office I can send you examples about it